# How to solve this equation $\sin 5x = \sin (x + \frac{\pi}{3})$

Tags: trigonometry

Could you give a hint how to solve this equation $\sin 5x=\sin (x + \frac{\pi}{3})$?

I tried to change $\sin 5x$ in function of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, but I wasn't able to go further.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**hint**
If $$\sin(X)=\sin(a)$$ then

$$X=a+2k\pi$$

OR

$$X=\pi-a+2k\pi$$

Comment: ... and vice versa.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You mean  $a=X+2K\pi$ or $a=\pi-X+2K\pi$.

Comment: I mean if either of the two equations are true, then the sines are equal.

Answer (score 1):

you want

$$5x= 2k\pi + (x + \pi/3)$$ or

$$ 5x= 2k\pi + \pi -(x + \pi/3)$$

Therefore we have $$ x=(6k+1)\pi/{12} $$ or

$$ x= (3k+1)\pi/9$$  where $k$ is an arbitrary integer.

Comment: The algebra is wrong here, _and_ the initial equation does not give equality when $k$ is odd.

Comment: The second solution seems incorrect.

Comment: Please check the edited answer again

Answer (score 1):

With Salahamam_Fatima's hint, suppose $a = x + \frac{\pi}{3}$

$sin(5x) = sin(\pi-(x+\frac{\pi}{3})+2k\pi)$

and

$sin(5x) = sin(x + \frac{\pi}{3}+2k\pi)$

Solve for x, and we get

$x = \frac{\pi}{9} + \frac{k\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{\pi}{12} + \frac{k\pi}{2}$

where k is an integer.